# Java Netbeans Code Transformation

Tags: java, netbeans

I am working with Java on netbeans IDE. With the help of netbeans code transformation i have found following codes which turns out to display the same thing using different methods. 
Following are the codes, here a is an ArrayList.

```
//code 1
for(int j=0;j<a.size();j++)
{
    System.out.println(a.get(j));
}
//code 2
for (Integer a1 : a) {
System.out.println(a1);
}
//code 3
a.stream().forEach((a1) -> {
System.out.println(a1);
});
//code 4
a.stream().forEach(new Consumer<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public void accept(Integer x1) {
            System.out.println(x1);
        }
    });
```

For the last code, 'java.util.function.Consumer' is imported.
I want to know is there any significant difference between these methods and if yes then what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd and 4th snippets, that create a Stream, would have some additional overhead, so they would be a little less efficient.

There's a 5th option that would be the shortest to write :

```
a.forEach(System.out::println)
```

Comment: That is rather useful, however i need a little more detail about their working for understanding differences between the codes.

Comment: @Piyush you should read about lambda expressions, Streams and method references to understand the 3rd and 4th examples, as well as my snippet.  I don't think the first two require any explanation,  since that's basic Java code

Comment: Other then shortening the length, does this method have another effect on code? Like making the code faster or something?

Comment: @PiyushVishwakarma well, the 1st and  2nd snippets, as well as my snippet,  should all have similar performance.  The other two might be slightly slower due to the overhead of a Stream.